# Kill a running subprocess created by popen from mac terminal

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I have a python script `myscript.py`

```
subprocess.Popen(my_command, shell=True)
```

I run `python3 myscript.py` from my terminal and now I couldn't stop the running `my_command` using `ctrl` + `c`. `my_command` will continue running.
Is there anyway I can stop it?

thanks!

Comment: You can use `killall my_command` to kill any processes matching `my_command`

Comment: @Barmar thanks, it works! I almost forgot the `killall` command

Answer (score 0):

can use psutil

```
import subprocess

import psutil


def destroyed(proc_pid):
    process = psutil.Process(proc_pid)
    for proc in process.children(recursive=True):
        proc.kill()
    process.kill()


proc = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", " 1000"], shell=True)
try:
    proc.wait(timeout=5)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    destroyed(proc.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Macbook Terminal, to suspend your Python operation, use <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

Type `jobs` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see a list of background processes:

```
[1] job1
[2] job2
```

Then type `kill %1` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quit job1